# overlay blinking image for a short time then stop

Tags: ffmpeg

## overlay blinking

The following code makes the overlay loop blink every 2 seconds,

enable=lt(mod(t,2),1)

But I want it to blink for a certain amount of time (flickering) and then just stay visible.

Please explain each expression.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 2nd element to the expression.

```
enable='lt(mod(t,2),1)+gt(t,20)'
```

This will keep the overlay steady after 20 seconds.

Comment: This code works partially. Please explain each expression. Also, how to change the start time? Start at 3s.